# PDF reader that will show 3+ pages horizontally

Tags: pdf-viewer

Is there a PDF reader (for Mac OSX or for Windows) that will show 3+ pages horizontally?

I looked everwhere and cannot find a reader with this feature.  Maybe there is a reason it is not possible?  If so, just looking for an answer.

Why?

1. I have a 4K monitor and would prefer to view pages in a 2highx3wide grid, scrollable if possible.
2. I want to read PDF sheet music, which is best when I can see as many pages as possible on the screen at a time.

Example not fitting requirement:

- For example, Adobe documentation says it only will do only a maximum of 2 horizontally:
  https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/adjusting-pdf-views.html

Comment: Workaround: If your PDF viewer contains a printer driver, you may print your file to a new document with multiple pages per sheet.